# API Gateway - File upload to Lambda function avoiding S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I'm trying to capture a POSTed file upload parameter in AWS Lambda via the API Gateway.

I'm sending the form data with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

However, the Lambda function / API Gateway is sending back an error along these lines:

```
Could not parse request body into json: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xbf\n at [Source: [B@24856f29; line: 1, column: 3]"
```

In the API 'Settings' area, I've set for 'Binary Media Types' application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but it's still treating the POSTed data as JSON.

I'm wondering how can I upload files to a Lambda function without having to go through S3 (my uploads are only 30kb and transient, no need to store them).

Comment: Related: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-content-encodings-examples-image-lambda.html#api-gateway-content-encodings-example-upload-image-to-lambda

Comment: I've found this solution: https://medium.com/@olotintemitope/how-to-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-using-nodejs-lambda-and-api-gateway-bae665127907 . It is what I need.